# Empty values sending FILE using FormData, AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When I send an AJAX request using FormData I don't get values ​​in either $ _POST or $ _FILES and I can't understand why is this happening.

This is the following form:

```
<form method="post" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">                       
   <input type="file" id="img" name="first_imp">                              
</form>
```

This is the Jquery code:

```
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("form1"));                   
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'/mod_tanque',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: {
            data:formData,
        },success (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
 });
```

And PHP file:

```
var_dump($_FILES);
var_dump($_POST);
```

When I show the content of $_FILE or $_POST, this is the result:

```
array(0) {}
array(0) {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you want to pass to the ajax `data` is the FormData object

Change

```
$.ajax({
     // ...
     data: {
        data:formData,
     },
```

To

```
$.ajax({
     // ...
     data: formData,
```

Comment: Thanks this got the jigsaw working for me, after about 40 alt answers!